# Simulation Nodes: How to restart extrude-loop from scratch?

Tags: simulation-nodes

I have this extrude-loop in Simulation Nodes.

How can I restart it from scratch every 4th second like a lightning that spawns from the same spot every 4th second?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chanfiroly's answer](https://twitter.com/chanfiroly/status/1671604758614769665) (at least as presented [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/295398/60486) ) won't work if the framerate multiplied by your desired bolt lifetime doesn't produce a whole number. For example:

- 23.976 FPS animation will jump through the 4 second mark
- a lifetime that isn't a whole number will be hard to hit exactly
- even if at first the animation works, it can stop working after a longer time: [A Shader Trick](http://the-witness.net/news/2022/02/a-shader-trick/)

So instead you should do this:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Even though, I replicated the network exactly. Why does it slow down from 60fps to even 20fps when one keeps playing the loop for 5000 frames? I can see in the spreadsheet that the vertices get resetted like they should.... weird

Comment: Ah, yes, it's because cache keeps building up - makes sense. Most probably happens with every type of network, so, gotta live with it. Okay. Good.

Comment: Would you know how to make the growth of the line gradually slow down during the 4 second-cycle, but still reset itself to grow full speed in the beginning of each cycle? The extrude-node's Offset Scale should be multiplied with 0.995 for every frame I think, but I can't get it to reset every 4 seconds...

Comment: Ah! I think I got it :) I divided the result from Modulo by 8 and Subtracted it from 0.5 and put that into the Extrude Mesh's Offset Scale - Seems to work how I like it to work.

Comment: @ManuJärvinen yep that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Chanfiroly's answer](https://twitter.com/chanfiroly/status/1671604758614769665) seemed to work :)

[image]